# Oracle - can not declare variables

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have strange problem, which I cannot find solution...

I am trying to check how syntax in Oracle works, just to get started, but I can't get even started, because I get:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'declare'.

This is what I am trying to execute:

```
declare log varchar(100);
begin
log := 'abc';
log := log || LENGTH(log);
dbms_output.put_line(log);
end;
```

Also tried

```
declare log varchar(100) := '';
```

None worked... What is the right syntax?

**EDIT**

Worth mentioning: I am connected to SQL Server engine.

Comment: Are you executing this inside of a proc or trigger, or just directly against SQL developer?  I'm not sure this would work outside of a proc.

Comment: In plain worksheet... I think I need to read about those "worksheets" etc. It is so different from MS SQL Server...

Comment: Your code works fine. see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4de26470039bfa1300c2598022721216)

Comment: Add a new line after DECLARE. "log" might be a reserved word for the logarithm function.

Comment: btw is this Oracle database? Error message appears to be SQL Server. This code works fine in Oracle.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit After renaming variable, adding new line - didn't work

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar It is SQL Developer :)

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar You are right... I am connected to SQL Server engine... but is it relevant?

Comment: No, I mean, you're connecting to SQL Server in your developer tool. Maybe you double check, you use the right connection.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar Yes! This means I have to use SQL Server syntax all the way?

Comment: You're connecting to SQL Server database from Oracle SQL developer and running an Oracle code. How do you think it's gonna work? Simply delete this question.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I think it is worth mentioning what you have said. I thought I will be able to write PL/SQL scripts in SQL Developer, despite the connection I am uisng

Comment: SQL Developer, is only an IDE.. You have to use the right syntax for the database you connect to.

Comment: Writing and executing are 2 different things?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar Ok, so I got it totally wrong... Thanks!

Comment: we do have translators for taking SQL Server code to execute in Oracle, but...yeah, you can't do this